# AWS API Gateway: Cloud Watch logs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS API Gateway that triggers a Lambda function (integration request type is `LAMBDA_PROXY`).

I am trying to add logs for the gateway's activities via Cloud Watch.

After following this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/), it is still not working.

The log role have the `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` permission and is set in the settings tab under `CloudWatch log role ARN`.

The stage have the following configurations under `Logs/Tracing`:

[image]

The logs group have the following configurations:

[image]

I am testing via postman and the Lambda is being triggered normally.

Comment: Are you seeing any failed requests to CloudWatch in CloudTrail?

Comment: @TomNijs what should I be looking for exactly?

Comment: Did you re-deploy the API after setting up the logs?

Comment: @Caldazar yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by one of the logging role's permission boundaries.

Configuring the necessary boundaries for my case solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing to check**, there is a global setting which is placed in **Settings** from your API Gateway console that you should have checked.

Check if you have input your **IAM Role ARN** that have the sufficient permissions into this place yet.

[image: apigw-cwlogs-settings]

**Second thing to check**, you should double-check that **IAM role trust relationship** value. Here is mine:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Third thing to check**, you should re-check your **Access Logs** format. Try using a sample one to check if it works or not?

```
{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", \
  "extendedRequestId":"$context.extendedRequestId", \
  "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", \
  "caller":"$context.identity.caller", \
  "user":"$context.identity.user", \
  "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", \
  "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod", \
  "resourcePath":"$context.resourcePath", \
  "status":"$context.status", \
  "protocol":"$context.protocol", \
  "responseLength":"$context.responseLength" \
}
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html

Comment: Thanks for the details, I tried the above and didn't work yet.

Comment: @MajedBadawi Have you re-deployed your API Gateway stage? Sometimes, I have to do this to make things affect.

Comment: Yes, I re-deployed

Comment: @MajedBadawi What is your Log Group ARN that you input above? Does it have `:*` in your ARN? If you copy it from AWS Console, delete the `:*` part and ensure only Log Group name instead.

Comment: Yes I removed it, they give you an error if you include it